# Redis - под него только впс брать?

Tags: хостинг, redis

Есть необходимость использовать Redis как кэш в проекте. 
Но так понимаю, что в обычные хостинги он не входит.

Под него только впс брать нужно, на впс самому настраивать апач\nginx и только так? ...

Comment: Можно взять облако в крупной компании и оплатить услуги расширенного администрирования/обслуживания ее администраторов/технической поддержки (если перенос бесплатен, то можно попытаться бесплатно получить обслуживание через менеджеров по продажам).

Comment: что такое обычный хостинг? некоторые хостинги предоставляют redis.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не видел на хостингах Redis, максимум Memcached

Comment: Например, beget.ru

Comment: На azure редис есть в готовом виде. Но дорого.

Comment: @PashaPash на beget возьму, устраивает

Comment: А зачем вы отметили как принятый ответ, который никак ваш вопрос не отвечает?

Answer (score 1):

Я пользуюсь хостингом [Бегет](https://beget.com/p123132) для простых проектов и сайтов. Но не смотря на то что это обычный хостинг, у них есть и Redis и Memcached, также у них доступен Tarantool и Shpinx.